# How to write a apex trigger before insert a data

Tags: apex, community, basics

How to write a apex trigger before,after insert a data!

I am new to salesforce i want to know about apex trigger can any one give some guideness

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must create trigger,either from eclipse, developer console or setup menu(for standard objects: Customize -> object Name -> Triggers, for custom objects : Create -> Objects - > find triggers related list on object).

When you see some block where you can put code - it is time for some apex :)

```
Trigger t on Account (before insert) { // this line define name of trigger and when it will be invoke

/** Here is place for some code**/

}
```

As you can see it is ridiculously easy :)

But as you said, you are newbie here, in Salesforce.
So I strongly advice to do what every newbie MUST do if he want to be a pro - start reading documentation and learn :)

Here is some piece of documentation, it should help you : 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_triggers.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_triggers.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce apex code developer doc is the best place to start of with.Please follow the [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_triggers.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_triggers.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) . If you are stuck at any point you can post your questions in stackexchange.